# Python dice simulation

Tags: python, random, dice

I'm a bit stuck on a homework question that simulates rolling dice.  The question asks to create a function that returns a random integer value from 1 to 6, and to create a main program that asks the user how many dice to roll(must be limited to 5 dice), and calls the function to print the generated values. So far I have this:

```
import random

def dice(number_of_dice):
    for i in range(0,number_of_dice):
        return random.randint(1,6)


number_of_dice = input("How many dice would you like to roll? ")
while number_of_dice >5:
    number_of_dice = input("You may only have a limit of 5 dice, enter a number under 5. " )
print dice(number_of_dice)
```

When running the program, it only returns one random integer value no matter what the "number_of_dice" input is. What exactly is wrong here?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The return statement will return immediately after the first entry into the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as your `dice` function executes and encounters the `return` statement for the first time, it returns without continuing the rest of the `for` loop.

To fix this, you can declare a local variable inside `dice` that holds the multiple results you want to return. Use statements like

```
retval = []

retval.append(...)

return retval
```

(I'll leave it to you to fill in the blanks.)

A more advanced use of Python involves using the `yield` statement to return a single value from a special kind of function called a *generator*, which remembers where it was and can be restarted later. However, it's worthwhile to get a firm grasp on the basics before using features like `yield`.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, got it working myself by adding all the numbers into one variable, and returning that variable just like you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dice(number_of_dice):
    for i in range(0,number_of_dice):
        yield random.randint(1,6)  #yield will successivly return as opposed to just return
```

now you can access dice like a list ...

Comment: Not really supposed to write the code for homework questions~

Comment: all i did was change one term for him

Answer (score 0):

You use a while loop like this

```
import random

from random import randint

while True:

  dice = input("how many dice would you like to roll?")

    prefix, middle, suffix = dice.partition("d")
```

for the d in the 2d6 etc

```
    for _ in range (int(prefix)):

      print (random.randint(1, int(suffix)))
```

Comment: You also have to put the print statment in your last line in an indent