# Making a program randomly roll a 6-sided die

Tags: python

I am trying to do this project but I am lost. This is the first time I have done a program like this and I don't know where to start. I tried to have the dice.roll = a range of 1 to 6, but I think I was not supposed to since it says the name "random" is not defined. I have no idea what I am doing incorrectly and do not have anyone available to explain.

```
# ************************

# Step 1: import from dice the Dice class

from dice import Dice

# Step 2: For the variable name dice, assign the Dice() class

class Dice():
    results=[]
# Step 3: Declare an empty results list

    results=[] 

# Step 4: Roll the dice 1000 times 


for roll_num in range(1000):
    dice.roll= random.randint(1,6)

# stores the results for each single dice roll in a list
    result = dice.roll()
    results.append(result)

# analyze the results
frequencies = []

# range starts at 0, increments by 1 and stops just before the last number
# Uses +1 to stop just before 7 for 1-6 sides

for value in range(1, dice.num_sides +1):

# Step 5: call the value as you count the results
    frequency = results.count()
# Step 6: similar to the results list, keep appending or adding the frequency
    frequencies.append()

# Step 7: Print the frequencies to the Python Shell
print()
```

Comment: `random` is a module that has to be imported. Are you sure you have imported the dependency? (i.e. `import random`)

Comment: My teacher is having us import this program for it. I am trying to figure out how to get the die to roll a 1000 times and am not understanding how.       from random import randint
class Dice():
    """A class for a single six-sided die"""

    def __init__(self, dice_sides=6):
        """A six-sided die."""
        self.dice_sides = dice_sides

    def roll(self):
        """Returns a random value between 1 and the number of sides."""
        return randint(1, self.dice_sides)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python dice simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771961/python-dice-simulation)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+dice There are many many people around who had the same homework.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I feel OP (original poster) lacks understanding for several python concepts.

1. import in the module

I believe you have a python file called `dice.py`, containing the definitions of the `Dice` class, probably as follows (from your comments)

```py
from random import randint
class Dice():
    """A class for a single six-sided die"""
    def __init__(self, dice_sides=6):
        """A six-sided die."""
        self.dice_sides = dice_sides

    def roll(self):
        """Returns a random value between 1 and the number of sides."""
        return randint(1, self.dice_sides)
```

You should know that a function `randint` in `random` is imported in the python file `dice.py`, and then one could use the functions in the file, like `randint(1, self.dice_sides)`.

(the return value of `Dice.roll()` should be `randint(1, self.dice_sides+1)`

2. instance of a class

After you import `Dice` from the module `dice`, you could instantiate the class like below.  This corrects your code in *Step 2*.

```py
adice = Dice()
# then this would be a 6-side dice
```

Then you could get a roll number from the variable, as it has method (that is, function in class) `roll`

```py
a_random_result = adice.roll()
print(a_random_result)
```

After this, you should get use a `for` cycle to get 1000 results and store them in `results`.

Comment: If you think he `lacks understanding for several python concepts` better post a link to a tutorial in the comments or find some duplicate question.

Comment: stackoverflow is (in my understanding) not supposed to be a custom-tutorial-collection, where people are teaching other people the most basic language skills over and over.

Comment: thanks, I could read the guide line for asking and answering questions and get more experience for  this.